# Order email not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-email

The Magento site can send emails from the contact form and when someone signs up.

BUT If a customer purchases an item, it does not send a confirmation receipt to that customer.

Comment: Other email is working except order?

Comment: Yes, on checkout the mail is not coming.